# How to get correct date from string date("Y-m-d")?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I use Angular 5.

I am going to convert string to date.

My code is:

```
const start_date = '2015-02-03';
const startDate = new Date(start_date);
console.log(startDate);
console.log(startDate.getDate()); // startDate.getDate() is my target
```

The output of this code is:

```
Mon Feb 02 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
2
```

But I want to get `3` as a result.

How can I solve this without using Timezone?

Comment: If all you want is the date, then `+start_date.slice(-2)` does the job without the vagaries of the built–in parser and in less code. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply.

Try like this:

```
const start_date = '2015-02-03';
const startDate = new Date(start_date + ' 00:00:00');
console.log(startDate);
console.log(startDate.getDate());
```

Comment: Non standard ISO format like that may parse differently in different browsers/environments

Comment: @Igor Carvalho, I solved it and it works well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Returns an invalid date in Safari as the format is not consistent with ECMA-262. Code only answers aren't helpful, you should explain why the OP has their issue and how your answer fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You can use [.toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) which returns the date in UTC time as function suggest.

In your case:

```
const start_date = '2015-02-03';
const startDate = new Date(start_date);
console.log(startDate);
console.log(startDate.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. What I want is to get the correct number of day(it's 3 in my question)